# How to create API in C# to push or receive data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I would like to create an API for my website to send and receive data. 
For example I need my customers to upload products, single or multiple items. Product feeds can be send daily, weekly or monthly.

Product Name: 
Product Color:
Product Weight:
Product Images:

Also I need functionality to send this data to another server. And it should be user friendly.

But I don't have any idea where to start, what technology to use to make it simple and sufficient.

I have background in Asp.Net, C#. It would be great to see an example how to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

Its better you go for the **WEB SERVICES (WCF SERVICE)** to achieve this easily.

Answer (score 1):

REST via WCF would be the best option. Here is a good article series introducing you to REST with WCF: [REST in WCF](http://www.robbagby.com/rest/rest-in-wcf-part-i-rest-overview/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct pieces of functionality here, and keep in mind that they should essentially be kept separate.  Each of them is defined by "who is integrating to whom."

In the first piece, you want to expose a web service API to which clients can connect and send/receive data (the latter of which is on request only).  How you want to define this web depends on how you want to expose it to clients, how they want to connect, etc.  Common options are:

- [SOAP Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx) (classic ASP .NET web service)
- [WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) (think of it as a more modern ASP .NET web service)

You can even expose a manual service by defining your own WSDL for clients to consume, or a service that accepts and returns JSON to be more JavaScript-friendly for clients, etc.  There are many options.  But the above two are your most common choices.

The second piece is where you want to "push" data to another service.  This is something that the other service needs to expose and you need to integrate to that.  So the design should begin on that side.  If you're in charge of that design, just approach it the same way as above.  Expose a service there and then, using the same technologies that expose the services, consume them in your application.

The main thing to keep in mind here is to keep the two separate, because trying to expose a web service which at the same time consumes another web service will likely lead to confusion and some non-obvious work-arounds.  These are separate concerns and need to keep separated on a logical level, even if the end user doesn't know how separated they are.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bare minimum WCF Service which returns a product in JSON. To try it out, create a .NET 4.0 Full Profile console application. Run the program, and put this in your browser's address bar: http://localhost:8080/productservice/Product/23

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFServiceExample
{

    public class Product
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    public interface IProductService
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Product/{id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        Product Product(string id);

    }
    public class ProductService : IProductService
    {

        public Product Product(string id)
        {
            return new Product { Id = id, Name = "A Sample Product" }; 
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static ServiceHost servHost;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartService();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void StartService()
        {
            servHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProductService));
            servHost.Open();
        }

        ~Program()
        {
            if (servHost != null)
            {
                servHost.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logKnownPii="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
                logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
            <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
                messageFlowTracing="true" />
        </diagnostics>
        <services>
            <service name="WCFServiceExample.ProductService">
                <endpoint
                  address="http://localhost:8080/productservice"
                  contract="WCFServiceExample.IProductService"
                  kind="webHttpEndpoint" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```